# Getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "null" does not exist in SpringCloudDataFlow

Tags: postgresql, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database “null” does not exist" in connecting PostgreSQL to my SpringCloudDataFlow Server App in PCF environment.

I have successfully performed following steps.

1. Deployed SCDF(Spring-Cloud-Dataflow) server in PCF (1.7.3 version)
2. Created PostgreSQL service instance with 'Standalone' plan. **Note:** I don't have any other database service available in PCF marketplace.
3. Connect to that instance (using host (IP) and autogenerated credentials) by a third party software and create database using script 'CREATE DATABASE scdf'
4. Bind 'PostgreSQL service instance' with 'SCDF server app'.
5. Set environment variables

   ```
   spring_datasource_driver_class_name = org.postgresql.Driver 
   spring_datasource_username [PostgreSQL_Instance_Autogenerated_Username]
   spring_datasource_password [PostgreSQL_Instance_Autogenerated_Password]
   spring_datasource_url "jdbc:postgresql://10.254.48.231:5432/scdf"
   ```

After setting environment variables, when I restart SCDF server app, it gives exception and crash the app

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database “null” does not exist

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

A good first step is to make sure the PostgreSQL service-instance is functional on PCF.

Perhaps you could connect to the host/user/pass from outside of PCF via a DB client tool or from other applications. If this is successful standalone, then there's something wrong in supplying the credentials to the SCDF-server.

It is unclear how you're supplying database properties to SCDF. You may have to wrap those "datasource" properties as a well-defined JSON, and provided as the value for `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` property attached to the SCDF-server. If you continue to see issues, please update the description with `manifest.yml` and other information about the environment.